# UAE: Voice/Video Calling using Data/WiFi in App - using Swift 4.0

Tags: ios, swift, video, call, voip

**I want to add the Voice/Video calling functionality in my iOS app using Swift 4.0.**

which are the third party frameworks I can refer?

> Also, I came across the news that VoIP is blocked in many countries
>   UAE is one of them. Can I achieve the calling features in UAE if YES
>   then How? My app will be only used in UAE country.

I refered: https://www.quora.com/Is-there-any-VoIP-that-still-works-in-Dubai-in-2018

Answer (score 0):

https://www.twilio.com/blog/2018/03/making-phone-calls-in-swift-with-twilio.html

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire

if let accountSID = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID"],
   let authToken = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN"] {

  let url = "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/\(accountSID)/Calls"
  let parameters = ["From": "YOUR_TWILIO_NUMBER", "To": "YOUR_PERSONAL_NUMBER", "Url": "YOUR_TWIML_URL"]

  Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters)
    .authenticate(user: accountSID, password: authToken)
    .responseJSON { response in
      debugPrint(response)
  }

  RunLoop.main.run()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but will what is the platform twilio usage? and will that work in UAE?